# Can you discover the source of the foreach() error?

Tags: php, scripting

I am writing a script to export a MySQL query as a CSV file. So far so good, except that I get an Invalid Argument for the second `foreach()` statement! I tried to use `mysql_data_seek` but that did not solve the problem. AFAK `$row` is an array so it should work.

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("12**strong text**7.0.0.1", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database", $conn); 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = 'uploads/'.strtotime("now").'.csv';

    $fp = fopen($filename,"w");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $seperator = "";
    $comma = "";

    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
        $comma = ",";
    }

    $seperator .= "\n";

    fputs($fp,$seperator);


    mysql_data_seek($sql, 0);

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) );
    {
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";
        foreach($row as $name => $value)
        {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$value);
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $seperator .= "\n";
        fputs($fp,$seperator);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}


?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `;` should be there after `while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) )`. It's likely cancelling the loop and not redefining the value of `$row`, meaning it's using the old array.

Comment: `;` at the end of while loop statement is the problem. It completes the block of the while loop.

Comment: What an eye! I have been searching for an hour.

Comment: http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/4319594_460s.jpg only you've added it

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get why you have added first foreach loop, you code should be as below

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("12**strong text**7.0.0.1", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database", $conn); 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $filename = 'uploads/'.strtotime("now").'.csv';

    $fp = fopen($filename,"w");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM master") or die(mysql_error());
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) );
    {
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";
        foreach($row as $name => $value)
        {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$value);
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $seperator .= "\n";
        fputs($fp,$seperator);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}


?>
```

Comment: The first foreach loop is used to output the name of the field headers, as denoted by 
$seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);

The second foreach loop is used to output the values of the field as denoted by 
$seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$value);